# Confused by boost build parameters

Tags: c++, boost, boost-build

Ok I realize this question has probably been asked several times before, but I cannot find a reasonable response to it.

Using g++4.9 under linux, I built boost like this. I somewhat randomly picked these values based on what I have been able to gather from documentation other internet suggestions:

```
sudo ./bjam -a -j8 variant=release link=static runtime-link=shared threading=multi install --build-type=complete --layout=tagged --with-thread stage
```

But I only see the mt (because I see the -mt in the name), shared and static libaries in `/usr/local/lib`. No, shared-non-threaded libraries?

I am confused by:

1. what is the difference between `link` and `runtime-link` ?
2. what is the difference between `threading=multi` and `--with-thread` ?

**How do I get both the multi-threaded and the non-mt shared libraries, with highest possible speed optimizations possible, built?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of this is documented at:

http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html

To answer 1: link indicates if the libraries that you create will be static or shared, while runtime-link indicates if your new libraries will use the shared or static native C and C++ libraries

To answer 2: threading=multi indicates that your new libraries will utilize the multi-threading capacities of your system. --with-thread means that you build the BOOST threading libraries. When building boost you have the options of building only a subset of the available libraries.

To build both the multi-thread and non-mt, use the options

./bjam .... threading=single threading=multi ....

a